# Can't parallelly operate sleep program

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

I would like to run 2 programs in parallel, like reminders in mobile but when the count starts it takes input but their will be no output until the time up.
Here is the code that I used in python

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


def timer(time, string):
    for i in range(time):
        sleep(1)
    print(string)


def timestart():
        wait = 0
        time = list(map(int, input("How long do i have to wait: ").split(':')))
        time = time[::-1]
        for i in range(len(time)):
            if i == 0:
                wait += time[i]
            else:
                wait += (60 ** 1)*time[i]
        stri = input("What should i remind You: ")
        t1 = Thread(target=timer(wait, stri))
        t1.start()


a = {
    "Who": "Hello What is your name",
    "Good": "Its good to meet you",
    "Start": "Its time to start"
}

timestart()
name = a["Who"]
print(a["Good"] + name)
print(a["Start"])
```

This is the output I got i put bold as output
**How long do i have to wait**: *30*
**What should i remind You:** *Time up*
*hello*
*no printing*
*only input*
*until time up*
**Time up
Its good to meet youHello What is your name

Its time to start**
I changed to multiprocessing can anyone help me idk how to do this

```
    t1 = Process(target=timer, args=(wait, stri, ))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

It gave me the same output

Comment: [Multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3044580/14277722) is single-threaded in CPython.

Comment: Ok i changed it to multi processing idk how to do this its complicated, can someone explain

Answer (score 0):

you write it wrong. `target` should filled with the function. You have to pass the parameters via `args`

```
def timestart():
    wait = 0
    time = list(map(int, input("How long do i have to wait: ").split(':')))
    time = time[::-1]
    for i in range(len(time)):
        if i == 0:
            wait += time[i]
        else:
            wait += (60 ** 1)*time[i]
    stri = input("What should i remind You: ")
    t1 = Thread(target=timer, args=(wait, stri))
    t1.start()
```

Comment: Same result no parallel operation happened it waited till time is up and then printed the rest